# Get the length between two dates in hours

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, healthkit

I am reading sleep data into my react-native app using `react-native-healthkit`, and I need to find a way to get the total amount of sleep time. The data is read in like this:

[image: js object]

If anyone has any ideas on the best way to handle this data, please let me know.

Comment: "The best way to handle this data" is very broad. What part don't you understand? How to turn the strings into dates? How to measure the elapsed time between two dates? All of those things have been completely explained on Stack Overflow already (many times).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extension Date {

    /// Hours since current date to given date
    /// - Parameter date: the date
    func hours(since date: Date) -> Int {
        let calendar = Calendar.current
        let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.hour], from: self, to: date)
        return dateComponents.month ?? 0
    }
}

date2.hours(since: date1)
```

Using `.timeIntervalSince` is a bad practice, because some hours may be shorter than other.

Answer (score 0):

> If anyone has any ideas on the best way to handle this data please let me know.

It really depends on how you're parsing that JSON data. I won't cover JSON parsing here because there are many, many tutorials and blog posts on that topic. [Here's one](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/swift-codable-with-custom-dates/) in case you're not sure where to start.

Your goal is to end up with date objects (`Date` in Swift, `NSDate` in Objective-C). For example, if you have the values as strings, you can use `DateFormatter` to parse the strings into `Date` objects.

Once you have those date objects you can use the operations that those objects supply to get a `TimeInterval`, which is a `double` representing an interval in seconds. Convert that to hours by dividing by 3600:

```
let interval = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
let hours = interval / 3600
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
   let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
    guard let startDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "yourStartDate"),
          let endDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "yourEndDate") else {
             return
        }
    let difference = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate)
```

If you are targeting iOS 13 and above you can use

`endDate.hours(since: startDate)`

instead of timeInterval

Comment: Do not try to second-guess ISO8601DateFormatter by writing your own.